# Чтение полей json в Unity

Tags: json, unity3d, парсер

Нужна помощь в чтении json средствами JsonUtility .

```
{"frames": {

"aa1.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":1,"y":1,"w":142,"h":142},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":142,"h":142},
    "sourceSize": {"w":142,"h":142},
    "pivot": {"x":0.5,"y":0.5}
},
"aa2.png":
{
    "frame": {"x":145,"y":1,"w":142,"h":142},
    "rotated": false,
    "trimmed": false,
    "spriteSourceSize": {"x":0,"y":0,"w":172,"h":172},
    "sourceSize": {"w":142,"h":142},
    "pivot": {"x":0.5,"y":0.5}
}}}
```

есть понимания в части получения значений полей

```
[System.Serializable]
public class V4
{
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int w;
    public int h;

    public V4() { }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class V2
{
    public int w;
    public int h;

    public V2() { }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class F2
{
    public int x;
    public int y;

    public F2() { }
}

[System.Serializable]
public class Frame
{
    public V4 frame;
    public bool rotated;
    public bool trimmed;
    public V4 spriteSourceSize;
    public V2 sourceSize;
    public F2 pivot;

    public Frame() { }
}
```

Нужно получать имя каждого объекта (aa1.png, aa2.png... и т.д.) и поля каждого объекта.

Спасибо

Answer (score 3):

Структура json, которую вы привели как пример - фактически Dictionary внутри Dictionary. Но, к сожалению, JsonUtility не поддерживает Dictionary. По этому, я бы рекомендовал вам использовать стороннее решение для ваших целей. К примеру, посмотрите в сторону [Newtonsoft.json](https://github.com/jilleJr/Newtonsoft.Json-for-Unity), который отлично зарекомендовал себя на огромном количестве проектов. У него гораздо больше возможностей, чем у Json Utility

Comment: Спасибо, за ответ.